# Динамический сайдбар в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Кто знает как реализовать такую задачу, буду очень признателен за подсказку! Есть вот такой сайдбар

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка ВСЕ это основная категория товара, все что ниже, это подкатегории. Всего 7 категорий товаров на сайте и у каждого по несколько подкатегорий. При выборе в меню соответствующей категории должен меняться сайдбар на соответствующий. Подскажите, как можно реализовать?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать новый видежет и зарегистрировать его через `register_widget` https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_widget. В примере 2 пример виджета.